# How to detect and extract symbol from image

Tags: android, image

From an image, I have to detect and extract the [Printing registration symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_registration). It is a symbol that can be change in dimension and proportion but has always the same structure: a cross and one or more concentric circles. After the detection of this symbol, it has to be saved as a vectorial image.

I have seen a lot of OCR for text detection but nothing about symbols.

Comment: A change in dimension or proportion makes things more difficult for: [OpenCV feature detection](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) or if you have/can create a source image set, use [ML image classification](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/practica/image-classification)

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of Printing registration symbols images in different dimensions and proportions and angles. Possibly, you can get multiple images from the internet. Train an ML model(for image classification) using these images. After training this model, you can pass the images to this model and it will detect if the images have a Printing registration symbol. The accuracy of the model will depend on the number of images you had used for training and the image classification algorithm used for training the model. After detecting the symbol, you can perform the next operations.

You can look on the internet if there is any image classification pre-trained model is available that can detect the Printing registration symbol.